# NextJS export , the results html files on the project images not loaded

Tags: html, next.js, export

```
    import React from "react";

export default function PromoBanner() {
  return (
    <section className="container mt-4 mb-grid-gutter">
      <div className="bg-faded-info rounded-3 py-4">
        <div className="row align-items-center">
          <div className="col-md-5">
            <div className="px-4 pe-sm-0 ps-sm-5">
              <span className="badge bg-danger">Limitli Süre</span>
              <h3 className="mt-4 mb-1 text-body fw-light">Small Title</h3>
              <h2 className="mb-1">En Son Teknoloji</h2>
              <p className="h5 text-body fw-light">
                product Title
              </p>
              <a className="btn btn-accent" href="#">
                Btn Text
                <i className="ci-arrow-right fs-ms ms-1" />
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-7 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <img
              src="/general/01.png"
              alt="Güç Kontrol"
              className="PromoBannerImage"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Here is my sample comp. When ı export my project the image does not show how can ı solve this problem ?   [image]

Here is my jsconfig.json file. With this the css files is uploading but not images uploading when ı check the browser's Network developer tab ı can not see any images.

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "."
}
```

}

[image]

This is my file structure.

This is out file.
[image]
This is the root files.
[image]
This is my Public folder.
[image]

This is in out file index.html
[image]

When I add a dot like "./general/01.png" the image show and again give an error ı mean When ı refresh my browser the images show just  1 second after that the images  does not show.

Comment: Where ist he image located? Is it under ```/pages/general/01.png```?

Comment: You have an issue with the path to your image. We can't help you without information about where it's located.

Comment: @maxeth the images is under the public file. There is more than one sub file here for example general/product/1.png

Comment: I edit this question and ı add some information abouth paths thaks for your answer @OGreeni

Comment: @Kubilay move your image to sit directly under the `public` folder, and import it as `/filename`.

Comment: I know but ı did not understand why it is not find ./images/a.png in public folder by the way when ı import the images like './products/p1.png' it show only one second after that it did not find images.